# How old is Indy that shipped with Delphi XE4?

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe4

I'm running into some problems with sending SMTP messages in XE4 64-bit, and it appears that it's happening somewhere deep in the guts of the Indy code.

It's the standard Indy code that shipped with XE4, but when I look at the headers at the top of each file, it appears that they haven't been updated since 2005!  Obviously there's something screwy going on here.

How old is the version of Indy that was shipped with XE4, and have there been significant improvements in Win64 compatibility since then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version shipped with XE4 is 10.6.0.4975.

```
ShowMessage('Indy version: ' + IdHTTP1.Version);
```

From the indy change log:

```
Indy 10.6.0 - XE4 Release
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r4986 | Indy-RemyLebeau | 2013-04-14 19:08:12 +0200 (Sun, 14 Apr 2013) | 1 line
```

So it's from mid April 2013.

The latest version is 10.6.0.5152. I don't see anything in the change log about 64 bit but a lot of the comments are really broad (e.g. "Patches from Jose Antonio Sanchez Lazaro")

http://indy.fulgan.com/indy10.changelog.txt

Comment: If you look in Indy's SVN, the XE4 release is tagged using `r4989`.  There were a few checkins that went into the XE4 release. `r4986` was probably the first checkin, but it was not the last.

Answer (score 4):

The comments you see at the top of each source file are remnants of another version control (TeamCoherence) that Indy stopped using years ago.  Indy uses SVN now, which does not store revision history in the source code.

Indy has supported 64-bit since at least XE2, when 64-bit was first added to Delphi (maybe even earlier, for FreePascal support).

Comment: Ah, that makes a bit more sense.  Are you aware of any bugs that would cause access violations in the Indy worker thread while sending SMTP messages in 64-bit?

Comment: No, I am not. If you are having a problem, post a new question about it.

Comment: Nevermind. I just managed to track down the source of the problem, and it was in our code.  Apparently the parameter lists for some Indy event handlers changed since this code was originally written, and nobody noticed until I tried to build a minimal repro case out of this.  No idea why it was ever working in 32-bit, but oh well...